# About SOLID principles, DI using containers and Unity: How to manage the DI mapping in the container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, solid-principles

Allright. I finally understood all those complicated concepts of DI even IoC, containers, and so on and on. But there is something I'm missing still.

Say that I have a class called `SomeClass` that will instaciate in his constructor one of the classes that implememnts `IFirstLevelOfAbstraction`. The classes that implements `IFirstLevelOfAbstraction` are `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`. Those classes I mentioned instanciate a class implementing `ISecondLevelOfAbstraction`, which are `SubClass3` and `SubClass4`.

TL;DR here is the image.

[image]

Using unity in my entry point this should look something like this:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<SomeClass>();
container.RegisterType<IFirstLevelOfAbstraction, SubClass1>();
container.RegisterType<IFirstLevelOfAbstraction, SubClass2>();
container.RegisterType<ISecondLevelOfAbstraction, SubClass3>();
container.RegisterType<ISecondLevelOfAbstraction, SubClass4>();
var someClass= container.Resolve<SomeClass>();
```

**Question Being:** How do I *choose* which path will the DI have in the container?

i.e The instance of `IFirstLevelOfAbstraction` being `SubClass1` and for `ISecondLevelOfAbstraction` being `SubClass4`.

How do I easily change this later on?

Having so many DI nested isn't an anti-pattern? Why? Why is this any good?

I feel like nobody uses this. It's not even native in C#.

Comment: Does `Class1` take `IFirstLevelOfAbstraction` as a constructor parameter?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes, it does.

Comment: Throw away your DI Container and adopt [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) instead; then you will automatically be able to configure your dependency graph exactly the way you want it, without having to learn yet another class library API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is not to register `SubClass1`, `SubClass2`,`SubClass3`, or `SubClass4` and then choose such dependencies when you resolve. Here is an example:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

var someClass = container.Resolve<SomeClass>(
    new DependencyOverride<IFirstLevelOfAbstraction>(new ResolvedParameter<SubClass1>()),
    new DependencyOverride<ISecondLevelOfAbstraction>(new ResolvedParameter<SubClass4>()));
```

If this is not an option for you (you don't want to specify anything at resolve time), you need to use [named registrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660853%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). I wouldn't recommend going that route though.

Since you have multiple implementations for a single interface, I recommend that you use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). See [my article here](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html) for a reason why.

Here is how your code would look like with Pure DI:

```
var someClass =
    new SomeClass(
        new SubClass1(
            new SubClass4()));
```

Comment: Okay let me read your article first, because I thought containers approach were supposed to "solve" the need of using so many nested constructors (Pure DI).